# Multiple objects same model loadMultiple()

Tags: php, yii2

In my view, I can have one or more combination of this, but when trying to print no of User with only one combination,
 In my controller I got count of 2

```
<input type="text" name="User[user_id][]" />
<input type="text" name="User[username][]" />
```

In my controller :

```
 $count = count(Yii::$app->request->post('User'));// return 2
```

My purpose of checking the count is to create a number of User instance/s, but since Im having trouble to get the right number of created user, I can't proceed, Can someone enlighten me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code to this:

```
<input type="text" name="User[0][user_id]" />
<input type="text" name="User[0][username]" />
<input type="text" name="User[1][user_id]" />
<input type="text" name="User[1][username]" />
<input type="text" name="User[2][user_id]" />
<input type="text" name="User[2][username]" />
```

And so on...
It returns 2 because you create `user_id` and `user_name` in the wrong dimension of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery and the `clone()` function, and auto-increment the ID to replace in the new cloned field.

**JSFiddle:** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wadeshuler/9ggyxy2w/2/)

---

**HTML:**

```
<form id="autoinc-yii2form">
    <div id="aiy2-fields">
        <div class="aiy2f-user-wrap" data-user-count="0">
            <div class="aiy2f-userid-wrap">
                User ID: <input type="text" name="User[0][user_id]" class="aiy2-userid" />
            </div>
            <div class="aiy2f-username-wrap">
                Username: <input type="text" name="User[0][username]" class="aiy2-username" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <button type="button" onClick="return adduser();">Add User</button>
</form>
```

**JQuery:**

```
function adduser() {
    var userCount = $("#aiy2-fields .aiy2f-user-wrap:last").data("user-count") + 1;
    var cloned = $("#aiy2-fields .aiy2f-user-wrap:last").clone();

    cloned.find(".aiy2-userid").attr("name", "User[" + userCount + "][user_id]");
    cloned.find(".aiy2-username").attr("name", "User[" + userCount + "][username]")

    cloned.attr("data-user-count", userCount);
    cloned.appendTo("#aiy2-fields");

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Do a var_dump($_POST) and you will see what you are getting. You have User array with 2 keys which means it has a length of 2.

Comment: Your name format isn't wrong. You are simply doing the count on the wrong variable. Do the var_dump and see for yourself. Do you plan to have multiple users for both fields?

Comment: Yes , I see the var_dump now. Yes, I need Controller to manipulate multiple users for  both fields.

Comment: Now you've seen the var_dump. What appears to be a solution for it? You should be able to figure it out now.

Comment: I cant figure it now. Im having trouble with this reference http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-tabular-input.html#creating-a-dynamic-set-of-new-records

Comment: You have to figure it out. Has nothing to do with Yii. You are getting an array  and you want to iterate through it with each user. Look at the current format you are getting, how do you change the format so it serves whatever your purpose.